# How to store the ticket details into database using cas

Tags: jdbc, ldap, single-sign-on, cas

I had created a simple application using **cas** Authentication. My login authentication is working properly and corresponding ticket is also generating after each successful login. But my requirement is to store details of ticket is to a database.

Any help is appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about service tickets ? What details do you want to store in database ?
Service tickets are a security element of CAS and are meant to have a very short lifetime : used once and destroyed quickly...

Comment: Thanks jleleu.....I am trying to store my ticket granting ticket into database. Tables are creating in database but its not inserting. Kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't already take a look at the documentation : https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/JpaTicketRegistry